# Migration to AndroidX

Tags: android, gradle, resources

Well, I started a migration to AndroidX from a year old project (untouched since then) and I have problems withs the resources and the gradle build. Im completely lost with the new namespaces, I changed some of them, I upgraded all the things AndroidStudio told me, but still not recognizing things on my project. I will paste both gradle here and Ill put the error below.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.usuario.tm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Error

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\Xrless\Desktop\Programing\TN\TM\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_principal.xml:34: error: attribute android:style not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Command: C:\Users\Xrless\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\cf456f090f0725907522fb6d2bec3322\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Xrless\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Xrless\Desktop\Programing\TN\TM\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Xrless\Desktop\Programing\TN\TM\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Xrless\Desktop\Programing\TN\TM\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Xrless\Desktop\Programing\TN\TM\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.usuario.tm\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Xrless\Desktop\Programing\TN\TM\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198973/7254873

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your activity_principal.xml. Try to change:

> android:style

to

> style

Also you need to add

> android.useAndroidX=true

to your **gradle.properties** file if you want to use androidX library instead of Support Library.

Comment: I have written a full article on the topic, especially the manual fixes, hopefully, it will elaborate further https://handyopinion.com/ultimate-guide-to-migrate-android-project-to-androidx/

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidStudio 3.2+ you can use Refactor | Migrate to AndroidX to upgrade a project.
For more go [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score 1):

I spent an entire night trying to solve this issue after the migration to androidX. Below are the few things I did for it to work:

**In gradle.property:**

```
dex.force.jumbo=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableD8=true
android.enableR8.libraries = false
android.enableR8 = false
```

**In build.gradle:**

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    compileSdkVersion 28
    …
}
//Use JDK1.8 and make sure the same is well specified in your gradle file.
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
//Exclude Guava libraries
 ...
configurations {
    ...
    implementation.exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}

//Make sure your firebase and google libraries are all updated
   ...
   implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
   ...
```

**After all these, few usual things:**

- Make sure you update your gradle to the latest version (3.4.2 as of now)
- the previous action will require android Studio version 3.4 and above
- Clear your Gradle caches(use this command if on macOs `rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/`)
- Invalidate caches and restart, ...
- The rest will be just to change few implementations that were not refactored properly.

Think all should be find after that. Hope it saves you some time.

Answer (score 0):

1. implementation androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1
2. implementation androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Nice, I changed both implementations and added the androix=true to the property file. 
The build gradle thing is not throwing errors anymore (I think) But my layouts are not visible on the design view

IMAGE OF THE PROBLEM

[image]

And this:

IMAGE OF THE PROBLEM 2

[image]

Comment: You have to manually update the layout references. The widgets will be referencing the old support library. You have to update all the references in each layout

Answer (score 0):

### open gralde.properties file add below line

> android.useAndroidX = true

Sync project

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is correct. But to help other guys, In complex projects, we found such kind of many errors which we need to fix manually. I have written a full article on the topic, especially the manual fixes. [Ultimate Guide to Migrate Android Project to AndroidX](https://handyopinion.com/ultimate-guide-to-migrate-android-project-to-androidx/).