# Firebase UI Database Implementation

Tags: android, database, firebase, dependencies

Tried to add Firebase UI implementation

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
```

in build.gradle file.

The following error was shown.

```
*ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0.
Affected Modules: app*
```

Please guide me how to resolve the issue.

I am using Android Studio 3.5.3

Other dependencies I have already implemented in the app

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
```

Comment: ERROR Message while implementing FirebaseUI after migrating to AndroidX
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0.
Could not download auto-value-annotations.jar (com.google.auto.value:auto-value
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': 
Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0.
Could not download auto-value-annotations.jar (com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5)

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0
```

Also upgrade to androidX. Check the following for more information:

From the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-6.0.md):

> FirebaseUI version 6.0.0 has no breaking API changes from version 5.1.0 but updates critical dependencies to new major versions.
>
> There are two major groups of changes:

- Convert all Android Support Library dependencies to AndroidX or Jetpack dependencies. For information on migrating to AndroidX see this guide.
- Update all Firebase and Google Play services dependencies to their latest major versions. For information on changes included in these SDKs visit the release notes.

Comment: When I was doing migrating to AndroidX, it shows _References to be changed_ in build.gradle `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0`. I dont know what to do now? Please help.

Comment: you need to change that dependency to androidx, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53205831/7015400 refactor and it will change everything for you

Comment: Yes, your answer has given me some help. But my issue not resolved yet. Having same error. Don't know what to do now?  I am not a professional coder. Just I have learned online. Now trying to use the knowledge what I gained. But facing problem. The intention of implementing firebase UI database is to use FirebaseRecyclerviewAdapter in my app. Any idea how to use it in my app

Comment: what problem are you getting now?

Comment: ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0.

Comment: Did you upgrade to androidx? And update the Firebase dependencies?

Comment: Yes, Firebase update also shows Error. Hence retained 16.0.5

Comment: I am struggling with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69260024/using-firebaserecycleradapter-causes-dependency-issues), too.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

- Press F4 to open Module settings
- Select Dependency
- Click Add new dependency
- Type firebase, search for firebase.ui and add its latest dependency.

Answer (score 0):

At last I was able to sync successfully without Error.

The final dependencies in the build.gradle file of the app.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha01'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
```